# Android: Accessing SharedPreferences inside a DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dialog, sharedpreferences

So I have an activity with a few buttons each one with a TextView bellow, when I click on the button appears a Dialog Fragment with an EditText and a 'Done' button, I write something in the EditText, click 'Done' and ti changes the Text bellow the button I clicked, that is working fine. What I need is to replace the previous text with the new text in the shared preferences I that I already have.

My SharedPreferences: `SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Opening the Dialog and passing the TextView's ID:

```
fm = getFragmentManager();
myFragment = new Fragment_Subject_Edit(); 

      FirstButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putInt("ID", FirstText.getId());
            myFragment.setArguments(data);

            myFragment.show(fm, "ClassEditor");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Recieve ID in the Dialog Fragment:

```
 if (getArguments() != null) {

        Bundle data = getArguments();
        int id = data.getInt("ID");

        mTextView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(id);

    }
```

Adding the new text to the TextView bellow the button:

```
 DoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String newText = mEditText.getText().toString();
            mTextView.setText(newText);
            getDialog().dismiss();

        }
    });
```

The question here is really just how to update the Shared Preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will simply use `Editor` to save your new data on `SharedPreferences`

So in this case your code will be like this

```
DoneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String newText = mEditText.getText().toString();
        mTextView.setText(newText);
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor .putString ("key","your_value");
        editor .commit();
        getDialog().dismiss();

    }
});
```

Comment: Okay that works, so now, do I have to create a condition for each key value or is there an easier way to check what button was clicked, and select the corresponding key?

Comment: You can `implement` `onClickListener` to your fragment and can check your conditions on `switch / case` blocks.